# Create a custom ControllerAttribute with a standardized RoutingAttribute nested in

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, routes

On the top of every of my controllers, I have these attributes :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
```

I'm trying to merge them, and to add a notion of "version" to the controller.

For example, if my api evolves, I don't want all my applications to crash because of a breaking change. So I want the route to be `/api/v1/[controller]` and if I update it, I'll create a new controller with a `/api/v2/[controller]` route. Both routes will be available at the same time, and I would be able to progressively update my applications to connect to the v2 of the api without any crash.

So here is the code I'm working on :

```
[Route($"api/v{ApiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class ExtendedApiControllerAttribute : ApiControllerAttribute
{
    public string ApiVersion { get; set; }

    public ExtendedApiControllerAttribute(string apiVersion): base()
    {
        ApiVersion = apiVersion;
    }
}
```

But I'm facing a bunch of problems.

First, I can't reference the `ApiVersion` field as easily as I wanted to. I get this error :

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ExtendedApiControllerAttribute.ApiVersion'

But even if I just ignore the "versioning" system, and switch to the simple Routing system `[Route("api/[controller]")]` on the ExtendedAttribute, the controller isn't accessible. I get a 404 error when I try to go on the corresponding endpoint (even if it still being available through Swagger).

How can I merge these functionalities in one unique Attribute like this one : `[ExtendedApiController("1")]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to version ASP.NET Core Web API, we could use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` package. You can refer to the following steps:

1. Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` package via NuGet.
2. Register the ReportApiVersions service in the ConfigureServices method (in asp.net 5, if you are using Asp.net 6, you can add it in the Program.cs file).

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddApiVersioning(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            x.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            x.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPIService", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }
   ```
3. Then, we can do versioning of Web API using the following methods: Query string, ​URL and HTTP header.

   From your description, you want to set the version via URL, if that is the case, you can add the route attribute as below:

   ```
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/{v:apiVersion}/todoV1")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoV1Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        //...
    }
   ```

Then, the request url as below:

[image]

More detail information, refer to this article:[API Versioning in ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/api-versioning-in-asp-net-core-web-api/)